# expected primary-expression before "else"

Tags: c, arrays

```
if (choice==1)

     for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        masivs[i][j]=rand();
        printf("Sakummasivs: \n");
            for(i=0;i<r;i++)
            {
            for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            printf("%7d", masivs[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
            }
      else if (choice==2)
      { 
       printf("Ievadiet skaitlus\n");

        for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
        masivs[i][j]=choice;
        }
        }
        else 
        for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        masivs[i][j]=rand();
        printf("Sakummasivs: \n");
            for(i=0;i<r;i++)
            {
            for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            printf("%7d", masivs[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
            }
```

Error is in this line but I don't understand why

```
else if (choice==2)
```

Comment: May be you missed a closing '}' ?

Comment: You need to close the for loop for `i` before putting the `else if`

Comment: Your tabbing is horrendous. Also, if you want more than one line to be executed by an `if`/`for` then the code needs to be in blocks `{` `}`

Comment: You need to learn, how to write FORMATED code. This is mess

Answer (score 2):

This for loop

```
 for(i=0;i<r;i++){
```

needs a closing brace.

This would be obvious if you used a consistent indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Scope defined by `{` and `}` matters:

```
if (choice==1)
    for(i=0;i<r;i++) {
        ...
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            ...
        }
else if (choice==2)
    ...
    }
```

should be:

```
if (choice==1) {
    for(i=0;i<r;i++) {
        ...
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
else if (choice==2) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest a C-pretty printer.  And then you might want to sprinkle left and right braces where the are needed logically.  One guess would be the following, removing the "//" comments prefixing the braces.

```
if (choice==1)
//{
    for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            masivs[i][j]=rand();
        printf("Sakummasivs: \n");
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c;j++)
                printf("%7d", masivs[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    //}
//}
else if (choice==2)
{ 
    printf("Ievadiet skaitlus\n");

    for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            masivs[i][j]=choice;
        }
    }
    else
    //{
        for(i=0;i<r;i++){
            for(j=0;j<c;j++)
                masivs[i][j]=rand();
            printf("Sakummasivs: \n");
            for(i=0;i<r;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<c;j++)
                    printf("%7d", masivs[i][j]);
                printf("\n");
            }
        //}
    //}
//}
```

like so, which is syntactically correct, but maybe not semantically correct.

```
if (choice==1)
{ 
    for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            masivs[i][j]=rand();
        printf("Sakummasivs: \n");
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c;j++)
                printf("%7d", masivs[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    } 
} 
else if (choice==2)
{ 
    printf("Ievadiet skaitlus\n");

    for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            masivs[i][j]=choice;
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        for(i=0;i<r;i++){
            for(j=0;j<c;j++)
                masivs[i][j]=rand();
            printf("Sakummasivs: \n");
            for(i=0;i<r;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<c;j++)
                    printf("%7d", masivs[i][j]);
                printf("\n");
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```